# jQuery .animate() doesn't fire the first time, after that it's working

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, anchor

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $.cacheImage(['bilder/in_bearbeitung.png'])

    var cache = {'': $('.startseite')};

  $(window).bind( 'hashchange', function(e) {

    var url = $.param.fragment();

    if (url == ("telefonmeeting.html") || url == ("vorteile.html") || url == ("faq.html") || url == ("flatrate.html") || url == ("unternehmen.html") || url == ("impressum.html") || url == ("kontakt.html") || url == ("agb.html") || url == ("facebook.html") || url == ("news.html") || url == ("links.html")) 

    {
    $( '.inhalt-container' ).fadeOut();

    }

    if ( cache[ url ] ) 

    {

    cache[ url ].fadeIn();      

    }

     if (url == ("telefonmeeting.html") || url == ("vorteile.html") || url == ("faq.html") || url == ("flatrate.html") || url == ("unternehmen.html") || url == ("impressum.html") || url == ("kontakt.html") || url == ("agb.html") || url == ("facebook.html") || url == ("news.html") || url == ("links.html"))

     {

        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'fast');

        cache[ url ] = $( '<div class="inhalt-"/>' )

            .appendTo( '.inhalt-container' )

        $( '.inhalt-container' ).load( url , function( data ){

        $(this).html( data );
        $(this).fadeIn();

        });

    }

    else if (url == ("_1") || url == ("_2"))

    {

        $('.inhalt-container, .link , .sublink').click(function(event){
            //prevent the default action for the click event
            event.preventDefault();

            //get the full url - like mysitecom/index.htm#home
            var full_url = this.href;

            //split the url by # and get the anchor target name - home in mysitecom/index.htm#home
            var parts = full_url.split("#");
            var trgt = parts[1];

            //get the top offset of the target anchor
            var target_offset = $("#"+trgt).offset();
            var target_top = target_offset.top;                          

            //goto that anchor by setting the body scroll top to anchor top
            $('html, body').animate({"scrollTop":target_top}, 750);

        });

    }

   })

  // Since the event is only triggered when the hash changes, we need to trigger
  // the event now, to handle the hash the page may have loaded with.
  $(window).trigger( 'hashchange' );

});

</script>
```

Comment: Did you debug and see what is the value of target_top?

Comment: Do you have a working demo, perhaps a jsfiddle?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Fj9LY/ Any other code or HTML markup that might interfere with this? What browser are you testing on?

Comment: I'm testing the website on Firefox 4.0

Comment: you can see the development page on [link](http://www.cosmonautica.de/dev/index.html). 3rd link "Fragen und Antworten" opens the anchors.Do you want me to do a jsFiddle?

Comment: I load my html with .load() if a navigation link is clicked,
else (-> anchor tags) I'm using the scroll code (see above)
to scroll to the anchors. By using alert in the code, it reveals
that the scroll code isn't executed 1st time.

Any help offered is appreciated.

Comment: DarthJDG: I suspect the problem to be because of the focus.
my page consists of head, navigation, content, and footer.
if i load html into the content with my anchor links, does it
have focus after loading? i could be happy if someone sheds some
ligt upon this. :) P.S. your sample works. (Outside the ajax load, mine does too.)

Comment: does anyone have the answer for my problem?

Comment: Could you use code tags? It makes it easier to solve the problem.

Comment: @kingjiv You could have left the original question on there.

Comment: @mosselman if you look through the edit history you will see that I did not delete anything.

Comment: My bad! sorry. Was confused as to what the original question was. Seems OP has lost interest.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, using console at least.

The problem is that the anchor-ed objects don't exist yet when animate wants to have it's way with it. For some reason it works a second time through though.

However the solution is as follows: use the 'live' method instead of 'click'. It looks like this:

```
$('.link , .sublink').live('click', function(event){
        //prevent the default action for the click event

        event.preventDefault();

        //get the full url - like mysitecom/index.htm#home

        var full_url = this.href;

        //split the url by # and get the anchor target name - home in mysitecom/index.htm#home

        var parts = full_url.split("#");

        var trgt = parts[1];

        //get the top offset of the target anchor

        var target_offset = $("#"+trgt).offset();

        var target_top = target_offset.top;

        //goto that anchor by setting the body scroll top to anchor top

        $('html, body').animate({"scrollTop":target_top}, 750);

    });
```

This worked for me when I pasted it in the console so I hope it works for you too.

By the way, to also solve that fade problem you are having. Use the callback method for fading like so:

```
$('.something').fadeOut('slow', function(){ $('.otherthing').fadeIn('slow'); });
```

That way, the fadein will only begin when the fadeout has stopped.

Have fun!